# Properly declaring smart pointers

Tags: c++

I'm a little confused by this:

```
int *pointer = new int[100];    // Yes
int array [] = new int[100];    // No
```

But:

```
unique_ptr<int*> pointer { new int[100] };    // No
unique_ptr<int[]> array { new int[100] };     // Yes
```

can someone explain the general principle involved here. I don't fully understand why the smart pointer semantics seem to run contrary to regular raw pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smart pointers are library code, so they work the way they do because someone designed them in that way.

In your first, naked-array-new code, the second line doesn't make sense syntactically, since you cannot initialize an array with a pointer, and `new` returns a pointer.

The `unique_ptr` example is also wrong; the corrected version makes a lot more sense:

```
//               +--------------+------------ pointer to int
//               V              V
std::unique_ptr<int>   p { new int; }
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p { new int[10]; }
//               ^                ^
//               +----------------+---------- pointer to first element
//                                            of an array of int
```

Spot the pattern?

The reason you need different template specializations is that you need to call either `delete` or `delete[]` on the pointer depending on how it was allocated, but you can't tell that just from looking at the raw pointer. (Also, the array version provides a handy `[]`-operator.)

Nothing is *stopping* you from mixing `unique_ptr<int>` and `new int[10]`, but it's a more or less subtle error that causes silent undefined behaviour (one more reason to never use `new` youreself and instead rely on `make_unique`!). By contrast, your first example is a simple syntactical error.

Comment: Oh I do actually. Interesting! So `unique_ptr<int*>` doesn't even make sense because I shouldn't be creating a raw pointer *within* a smart pointer. That helps.

Comment: Is `unique_ptr` able to determine whether it should call `delete` or `delete[]`?

Comment: @sircodesalot: `unique_ptr` is a *template*. `unique_ptr<T>` uses `delete`, and `unique_ptr<T[]>` uses `delete[]` (where `T` is a non-array type) -- *you* decide.

Comment: Ah ok. Got it. Learned two new things. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I agree 100% with Kerrek SB answer. Here, I would like just to add another powerful possibility. You can also define your custom deleter class

```
 auto deleter= [](int* ptr){delete[] ptr;};
 std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(deleter)> ptr4(new int[100], deleter);
```

This looks complicated, but it can be quite useful if, for example, you need to call some C library that requires the heap allocation of C structs

Concrete example: GSL GNU scientific library. Integration routine requires the allocation of a struct called "gsl_integration_workspace". In this case, you can use the following code to ensure that your code is exception safe

```
 auto deleter= [](gsl_integration_workspace* ptr) {
   gsl_integration_workspace_free(ptr);
 };
 std::unique_ptr<gsl_integration_workspace, decltype(deleter)> ptr4 (
 gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (2000), deleter);
```

As Kerrek SB said, because smart pointers are library code, they provide more powerful ways to manage memory than raw pointers.